# C# Visual Studio Local Database Connection

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, dataset

I try to connect s visual Studio local database to my C# program. But in all examples or tutorials they use a form to display the databases value. But so I want to connect without the form.

My database called User.mdf and visual studio maked a file called UserDataSet with two methods UserDataSet and TableTableAdapter (my table called Table ^^).

After hours and hours I tried and looked online I'm still not able to write and read the databases value.

I hope you can help me..

Kind regards

Ascawath

Answer (score 0):

You can use ado.net classes to do all operations in database without a form.

Try the following examples: [ADO.NET Code Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-code-examples)

Just modify the connection string for your local database.

Answer (score 0):

in Web.config

```
 <appSettings>
<add key="ConnectionString" value="Data Source=youSourceName;Initial Catalog=User;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=youIDhere;Password=yourPassworHere"/>     
       </appSettings>
```

in your Webpage

```
public DataSet Local_GetDataSet(string SQL)
    {

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString());
            SqlDataAdapter adapter;
            try
            {

                adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, connection);
                adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = CommandTimeOut;
                DataSet mydata = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(mydata);
                adapter.Dispose();
                connection.Close();
                return mydata;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed) connection.Close();
                throw new Exception("Data Base Error: " + e.Message);

            }



    }
```